# Transferring Contents of Crystal Report to a Text File ANSI Format

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

Is there any way to export the contents of a Crystal Report to a text File - I am using VS 2005.

Comment: I assume this is about the contents of the report definition, not about the output from a report?

Comment: I have a report .rpt and I want to Export its contents to Text File

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to export to rtf/html and strip the tags

Answer (score 0):

Set the ReportDocument object FormatOptions.ExportFormatType = TabSeperatedText, before you call ReportDocument.Export()